# Unix-Like C++ Program String Parsing

Tags: c++, string, parsing

I am working on a unix-like file system and I need to take in `commands` from the command line. Some commands are one argument like `mkfs`, `ls`, etc. But some are two commands like `mkdir foo`, `rmfile hello`. My question is, how can I parse the string to take in a command (cmd), but also take in a second argument (next)? Here is my code so far: (I have not included the functions for the sake of space)

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    string cmd;
    string next;


    while (1){
        cout << "Russ_John_Shell> ";
        cin >> cmd;



        //Checks to see whether the string has a file/directory name after the command
        if (next == ""){
            //mkfs command
            if (cmd == "mkfs"){
                makeFS();
            }
            //exit command
            else if (cmd == "exit"){
                exitShell();
            } 
            //ls command
            else if (cmd == "ls"){
                listDir();
            }
            //command not recognized at all
            else {
                printf("Command not recognized.\n");
            }

        }
        else{

            //mkdir command
            if (cmd == "mkdir"){
                makeDir(next);
            }
            //rmdir command
            else if (cmd == "rmdie"){
                remDir(cmd);
            }
            //cd command
            else if (cmd == "cd"){
                changeDir(next);
            }
            //stat command
            else if (cmd == "stat"){
                status(next);
            }
            //mkfile command
            else if (cmd == "mkfile"){
                makeFile(next);
            }
            //rmfile command
            else if (cmd == "rmfile"){
                remFile(next);
            }
            //command not recognized at all
            else {
                printf("Command not recognized.\n");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Use [`std::string::find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) to look for whitespace, and if found then use [`std::string::substr()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) to extract substrings on either side of the whitespace.  Or, look at using [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) with [`operator>>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_ltltgtgt) or [`std::getline()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read whitespace-separated substrings.

Comment: argv[0] holds the name of the program itself and argv[1] is a pointer to the first command line argument supplied, and *argv[n] is the last argument.argv[1] will contains the command and argv[2] will contains the first argument.

Comment: @user1438832: that only applies when processing command-line arguments that are passed to the program when it first starts.  That does not apply when parsing other kinds of strings, like user-prompted values once the program is up and running, like shown in the OP's example.

Comment: Sorry i didnt see that.use  istringstream iss(cmd);
vector<string> tokens;
copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss),
     istream_iterator<string>(),
     back_inserter(tokens));